# FindElementByXPath from cellvalue in sheet

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

Is there a way to use a cell's value as the path in `FindElementByXPath`?
I use VBA in Excel and Selenium

Example:

```
Active cell "//*[@id="content"]/div[1]/div"

testPath=ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).value

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).value = driver.FindElementByXPath("testpath")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### (Double) Double Quotes

- Use `Option Explicit` to learn to solve errors on your own.
- `ActiveCell.Value` is the same as `ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Value` so `.Offset(0, 0)` is redundant.
- `TestPath` is a variable so you **must not** use double quotes to refer to it.
- To write your given string to a variable, you have to use double double-quotes (`""`) which is shown in the second procedure. Test it to see for yourself.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub ActiveCellTestPath()
    
    ' ...
    
    Dim TestPath As String
    TestPath = ActiveCell.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = driver.FindElementByXPath(TestPath)

    ' ...

End Sub

Sub DoubleQuotes()
    Dim TestPath As String
    TestPath = "//*[@id=""content""]/div[1]/div"
    Debug.Print TestPath
End Sub
```